# Transfer all messages of thunderbird with windows 7 to thunderbird ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, backup, thunderbird

How can I transfer all messages and contacts of thunderbird with windows 7 to thunderbird ubuntu 14.04?

I know that have a free app called [mozbackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/). But it don't works with linux.

There a way that can I make this moving?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the Q&A here help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/229779/transfer-thunderbird-17-profile-on-win7-to-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, copy the contents of `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles` on your Windows 7 machine to your Linux machine. Make sure you get atleast one folder with a name consisting of a random string of characters and then a name - e.g. `x90j7qn5.Default User`

Then create a directory called `~/.thunderbird`, and copy the files into it, and note down the name of the file. Then run `thunderbird -profilemanager` to open this:

[image: Thunderbird profile manager]

Click <kbd>Create Profile...</kbd>, and pick the location of the file you just copied to `~/thunderbird` (e.g. `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/thunderbird/x90j7qn5.Default User`)

Though apparently this should work cross-platform, I think you may need the same or similar versions of Thunderbird for this to work properly.

**Source:** http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-back-up-and-migrate-a-thunderbird-profile-and-folders/