# Trying to find and save my Thunderbird profile folder, after Windows 10 crashed, with the help of Ubuntu desktop testversion usb stick

Tags: thunderbird

After a Windows 10 total system crash, while "Thunderbird" was open, I am now trying to save with Ubuntu (USB stick test version) all personal data such as my Thunderbird profile, before I have to reinstall Windows 10 again. I didn't create any backup of my Thunderbird profile.

Is there any chance to get access to my profile folder to save it with the test version of Ubuntu on the same computer while Thunderbird seems to be open in the background and where I can find the profile folder on the Ubuntu desktop?

I know the profile location under Windows `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles` but under Ubuntu searching for `Users/AppData/Roaming/Thunderbird` there are no results and I don't know why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access Windows files from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433591/how-can-i-access-windows-files-from-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transfer Thunderbird (17) Profile on Win7 to Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229779/transfer-thunderbird-17-profile-on-win7-to-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are searching under `Users/AppData/Roaming/Thunderbird`, but (and I may be wrong) it *sounds* like you are looking on the incorrect disk or partition.

You need to being looking on the Windows partition or disk, *not* the Ubuntu partition. Assuming that you are using the default Ubuntu file manager, Nautilus, the Windows partition or disk is usually listed in the GUI, in the left hand side bar as "Other Locations", or under "Devices". Open either, and then the appropriate partition, to see the contents of your Windows installation.

[image: Windows partition in Nautilus]

Now, you should be able to access your files.

For further information, see [How can I access Windows files from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/433591/348964)

Also, you appear to have omitted your Windows username from the search path. You should be looking under `Users/<Windows User Name>AppData/Roaming/Thunderbird`.